# Setting local variables to a function instead of using globals optimize the function

Tags: python, local-variables, function-parameter

In the documentation for the itertools module I found this comment

```
def dotproduct(vec1, vec2):
    return sum(imap(operator.mul, vec1, vec2))
```

> **Note, many of the above recipes can be optimized by replacing global
>   lookups with local variables defined as default values. For example,
>   the dotproduct recipe can be written as:**

```
def dotproduct(vec1, vec2, sum=sum, imap=imap, mul=operator.mul):
    return sum(imap(mul, vec1, vec2))
```

How is it?.
Is there a practical noticeable speed-up (that could balance the inconvenience of the larger function signature)?
In which specific conditions the use of local variables in a case as the one shown would be relevant?.

**Edit:** I tested with timeit and there is any relevant difference.
For two 40-items lists as vec1, vec2:

> global lookup -> 3.22720959404
>   local  lookup   -> 3.19884065683

that is, only ca. 1% gain.

Comment: If you call a method massive number of times, you can consider creating an alias `func = module.func` to prevent lookups within module every time you refer to the method. I wouldn't bother though, I never found it noticeably faster and it often just makes code harder to read. Test for yourself and decide.

Comment: I really hate that specific example. Suppose someone misstypes `dotproduct((1,2),(3,4))` as `dotproduct(1,2,3,4)` (I've done similar when passing a several arguments to a function that really expected a single argument which is a list of values). With the first definition, the user would get a TypeError for passing the wrong number of arguments. With the second definition, the user would silently overwrite `sum` and `imap`. That would be surprising to say the least.

Comment: A 1% gain is not a significant difference; it could (!) be significant if it stayed 1% as the input size grew toward infinity, but then still, NumPy does dot products several orders of magnitude faster. I wouldn't change an interface for such a minute benefit; this is premature optimization.

Comment: @eryksun, That's pretty cool! I hadn't seen that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a practical noticeable speed-up (that could balance the inconvenience of the larger function signature)?

I very much doubt it, as the lookups occur once each in the original definition. Note that you've changed the meaning of the function.

> In which specific conditions the use of local variables in a case as the one shown would be relevant?

Only inside a tight loop; in this case, if `dot_product` where used in say a very large matrix multiplication (which you wouldn't do in pure Python anyway, let alone with iterators).

**EDIT**: I just disassembled both functions and my hunch was wrong, though my point still stands:

```
>>> def dotproduct(vec1, vec2):
...     return sum(imap(operator.mul, vec1, vec2))
...
>>> dis.dis(dotproduct)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (sum)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (imap)
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (operator)
              9 LOAD_ATTR                3 (mul)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (vec1)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (vec2)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             21 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             24 RETURN_VALUE
>>> def dotproduct(vec1, vec2, sum=sum, imap=imap, mul=operator.mul):
...     return sum(imap(mul, vec1, vec2))
...
>>> dis.dis(dotproduct)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                2 (sum)
              3 LOAD_FAST                3 (imap)
              6 LOAD_FAST                4 (mul)
              9 LOAD_FAST                0 (vec1)
             12 LOAD_FAST                1 (vec2)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            3
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: "Note that you've changed the meaning of the function" Not sure what you mean. Could you explain it?.

Comment: Default operators are only read once (otherwise this wouldn't work as an optimization). Therefore if you change one of those afterwards, you won't notice this. Now obviously highly unlikely here, but still worth remembering

Comment: @joaquin: what Voo says, plus the more fundamental change that the number of arguments went from two to five.

Comment: thanks. I understand. Then, we can conclude that the comment in docs is probably an overstatement. :)

Comment: Once upon a time, I'd say before Python 2.1 or so, global lookups were much slower than local lookups. Back then this style of passing globals into functions was more common but today the difference is so small it hardly matters.